# Newly created SXA indexes are not showing up in Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: sxa, solr

Followed the below steps to add new sxa cores in the solr 6.6.2

1.Duplicated core directory created for sitecore_master_index (or company_name_master_index) twice and rename to:

- sitecore_sxa_web_index
- sitecore_sxa_master_index

2.In those two folders, removed everything besides the conf directory.
On the Solr web interface, click Core Admin and click Add Core to add sitecore_sxa_master_index. Did the same for sitecore_sxa_web_index.

3.In Sitecore, log in to the Launchpad and open the Control Panel.
In the Indexing section of Indexing Manager dialog box sitecore_sxa_master_index and sitecore_sxa_web_index, are not visble.
Is there any other configurations which needs to be added in sitecore ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119317/discussion-on-question-by-vinaya-newly-created-sxa-indexes-are-not-showing-up-in).